# How can I set element for entire width of the page? (Android)

Tags: android, width, screen, android-relativelayout, resolution

I want to set the "layoutAtendenteBalao" element for the entire width of the page. I tried to set it to `<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>`, but it did not work.

**styles.xml**

```
<!--<style name="layoutAtendente">
    <item name="android:layout_width">560px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">400px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
</style>-->

<style name="layoutAtendenteBalao">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">210px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">176px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">140px</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/borda_balao</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="campoAtendenteBalaoTexto">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
</style>

<!--<style name="imagemAtendente">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">70px</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/d1280_800_atendente</item>
</style>-->

<style name="atendenteBalaoProduto">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProduto1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">50px</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProduto2">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">30px</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoNome">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoImagem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">120dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">85dp</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoValor">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoDescricao">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoRotuloQuantidade">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:text">Quantidade</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoQuantidade">
    <item name="android:layout_width">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="android:digits">1234567890</item>
    <item name="android:maxLength">5</item>
    <item name="android:text">999</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoUnidade">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoMenosMais">
    <item name="android:layout_width">50px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>
</style>
```

**atendente.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--  
<ImageView
    style="@style/imagemAtendente"
    android:id="@+atendente/imgAtendente"/>
-->
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/layoutAtendenteBalao"
    android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalao">

    <TextView
        style="@style/campoAtendenteBalaoTexto"
        android:id="@+atendente/txtTexto"/>

    <!-- Venda Orientada -->
    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/atendenteBalaoVO"
        android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalaoVO">"

        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTexto1"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOTexto1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTextoQuantidadeTexto2">"

            <EditText
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOQuantidade"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTexto2"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOTexto2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOMais"
            android:id="@+atendente/btnAtendenteBalaoVOMais"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOMenos"
            android:id="@+atendente/btnAtendenteBalaoVOMenos"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto"
        android:id="@+atendente/lnrProduto">

        <!-- Nome do Produto -->
        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoNome"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoNome"/>

        <!-- Descrição do produto -->
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto1"
            android:id="@+atendente/lnrAtendenteBalaoProduto1">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoImagem"
                android:id="@+atendente/imgProduto"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoDescricao"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoDescricao"/>

        </LinearLayout>        

        <!-- Valor do produto -->
        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoValor"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoValor"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto2"
            android:id="@+atendente/lnrProdutoQuantidade"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoRotuloQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoQuantidadeRotulo" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoQuantidade"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:digits="0123456789,." 
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoUnidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoUnidade"/>

            <Button
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoMenosMais"
                android:id="@+atendente/btnQtdeMenos"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoMenosMais"
                android:id="@+atendente/btnQtdeMais"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:layout_width` in *styles.xml* never worked great for me.

Always specify it in the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/layoutAtendenteBalao"
    android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210px">
```

Comment: I tried this, but the object isn't the entire screen width [image](https://mega.co.nz/#!qFQyRBBK!lpgP5eMoSOVi3Y5wC_4pu9CEKQT4l9FFYQ54CczYF40)

Answer (score 0):

You could use LayoutParams for dynamically setting of width and height. Something like this:

```
RelativeLayout layoutAtendenteBalao = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rltAtendenteBalao);
layoutAtendenteBalao.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: In your activity, where you load your elements